# How to add categories for pages only?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I have added this function in my functions.php file to show category option for wordpress pages. It works fine.

```
function support_category_for_pages() {  
    // Add category support to pages
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'page');  
}
add_action( 'init', 'support_category_for_pages' );
```

But is it possible to show/limit some categories for pages only(they must not appear under posts) ?

I hope I am writing this correctly. Basically the requirement is to keep different categories for post & pages and they should not appear in each other's category option.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches i can think off. I am not sure how you want it to work regarding the archive page and search page so second approach may not work for you.

First solution creating templates:
For example category-news.php

Inside you can modify the query specificly for this category

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'posts'
//add more arguments if needed
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
      $the_query->the_post();
      // Do Stuff
    } // end while
} // endif

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Second solution using pre_get_posts:

```
 function wp50_exclude_post_type_pages() {
 //in the array you can add ids, slugs or names
 if ( is_category( array( 9, 'cat2', 'Category 3' )) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
   //here we tell the query to show posts type only 
   $query->set( 'post_type', 'posts' );
   return $query;
 }
 
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wp50_exclude_post_type_pages');
```

Comment: Just tried this and the website(https://generatewp.com/taxonomy/)  but it didn't work. Thank you for trying help.

Comment: Okay i think i missunderstood what you are trying to do. The above its not working because its different taxonomy and you need to presave your permalinks and have template for the new taxonomy. But i think i know what you want and there is a easy solution. I have edited my answer.